# Spring security 5 - UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and basic authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to implement simple security for a small API school project and am a bit confused and overwhelmed. I followed 
[this blog post.](https://grobmeier.solutions/spring-security-5-jwt-basic-auth.html)

Everything works and I'm able to login and receive a jwt token. However login is currently performed by sending the username and password along with the URL as query parameters. That is of course something I would like to avoid.

I have tried adding httpbasic to the security configuration like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
           .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtAudience, jwtIssuer, jwtSecret, jwtType))
           .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                   authorizeRequests
                          .antMatchers("/board/**").hasAnyRole("MEMBER", "BOARD")
                          .antMatchers("/members/**").hasRole("MEMBER")
                          .anyRequest().authenticated()
           )
           .httpbasic().and().
           .sessionManagement()
           .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

Login however ceases to work and I constantly get an unauthorized while trying basicAuth with postman.

So my question is: How can I change the behaviour of these code snippets to accept basic authentication and not send user credentials by URL? Do I have to override the AttemptAuthentication method too?

Comment: Token authentication is used when you have HTTPS and the credentials are send with POST, not GET. If you put your token endpoint in POST and HTTPS you are secure, otherwise you will be unsecure (clear text passwords on the wire).

Comment: @FaustoCarvalhoMarquesSilva can you recommend a decent guide? I've been searching for a while now, but can't really get it to work (https)

Comment: Maybe https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/